# STS 2.5.2 showing error error occurred during initialization of vm could not reserve enough space for object heap eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using **STS2.5.5 with jdk 1.6** in my system with **32 BIT winx Xp** 
it was working fine for few HRs when i installed it for the first time, 
after that when i restart STS it started showing exception **Failed Initialize** 
when i start the TC it throws hte exception 
**error occurred during initialization of vm could not reserve enough space for object heap eclipse**
It is working fine in another system with same config, 
to resolve this if i **delete STS and reinstall STS** it works fine but again throws same error if i close STS and open it
can anybody help me, 
i am also not able to change the size in my sts.ini
if i increase memory and start STS then it will not start.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your system, not with STS or Java.

Specifically, your system doesn't have enough physical memory and / or enough swap space configured to allow it to start the JVM.

Increasing the memory size in "sts.ini" won't help.  In fact it will only make things worse.  The problem is that that the JVM is already asking for more virtual memory than your system can provide.

---

On reflection, the problem could be that you've got multiple instances "running".  Check the Windows TaskManager and kill off any old STS / Eclipse instances before trying again.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,i verified this and i am sure that there are no multiple instances of STS running or eclipse running

Comment: Iam Still Getting
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Comment: I found the exact issue here it is,every time i restart the STS or leave it idle for long time the VM args are geting changed the -xmx is getting changed to 1024 where for my system it should be 512 can anybody help me why vm args getting changed??